# cannot access integers in a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

The following program is running into segmentation fault and I cannot figure why.

```
vector<int> *A::B(vector<int> *prefix, vector<int> *projected_tids, int support) {
    vector<int> *result = NULL;
    for(it_vec it = projected_tids->begin(); it != projected_tids->end(); ++it) {
        if(projected_tids == NULL) {                           
            cout<<"NULL";                                  
        } else {                                               
            cout<<"abc"<<endl;                             
            cout<<&projected_tids<<"address"<<endl;        
        }                                                      
        cout<<"here"<<projected_tids->size()<<" "<<prefix->size()<<endl;
        cout<<"iteration: "<<projected_tids->at(1)<<endl;      //seg fault here
        map<int, bool> *transaction = (*processed_input)[*it]; //seg fault here as well, because of *it
        bool found = true;
//some more code
    }
}
```

The prompt looks like this:

```
abc
0x7ffe3894a198address
here16 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

GDB is also confusing, might be because I am using C++ after a long time, but I cannot figure why? Below is GDB output:

```
(gdb) print projected_tids == (void *)0
$14 = false
(gdb) print *(projected_tids._M_impl._M_start)@1
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) print *(projected_tids._M_impl._M_start)@3
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) print projected_tids
$15 = (std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > *) 0x60e000
```

The allocation of pointer to vector is done as in the calling class:

```
vector<int> *projected_tids = new vector<int>();
```

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Sorry if your vector has a single element shouldn't you be accessing element `0`? `projected_tids->at(0)` it's also safer to use iterators to access the elements and test if they are not equal to the `end` of the vector

Comment: @EdChum `projected_tids` has size 16, the other vector  has size 1.

Comment: You first access `projected_tids->begin()` *then* check if projected_tids is null. Isn't it a bit late?

Comment: @n.m it is for demonstration purposes. I initially even did not had any `cout` and was using `gdb`. Could not solve problem, so added some print statements to post on SO so that it is easily understood.

Comment: You also mark two lines with "segmentation fault", do you have it at both lines?

Comment: Gdb should be able to print your vector without you resorting to low level tricks. Have you tried `print *projected_tids`?

Comment: @n.m yes. On different runs of the same program. If I comment the first line, it give `seg fault` on second. Alternatively, I tried printing `cout<<*it<<endl` which resulted in `seg fault` as well.

Comment: @n.m. I tried just now and got this error: `(gdb) print *projected_tids
$16 = std::vector of length 16, capacity 4 = {Cannot access memory at address 0x0
`

Comment: `length 16, capacity 4`. That seems off. Are you absolutely sure that pointer points to a valid `std::vector`? Why are you dynamically allocating the vector in the first place?

Comment: @TartanLlama yes. I am allocating it as  `vector<int> *projected_tids = new vector<int>();` in another function which calls this function.

Comment: Most likely that memory is getting scribbled over with something else, or maybe you `delete` it. Dynamically allocating a `std::vector` doesn't usually make sense, as it already does dynamic allocation internally.

Comment: @TartanLlama I am dealing with large objects and just want to maintain a single copy of everything to save memory. Does not want to have local references to anything as in that case lot of allocation and would happen

Comment: Why all the pointers?? What a mess.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam you can keep a single copy without using dynamic allocation. Just construct the `std::vector` and pass references everywhere.

Comment: `length 16, capacity 4` This alone absolutely means your memory is corrupt. Capacity must always be >= length.

Comment: @n.m any suggestions on what could be wrong?

Comment: The corruption probably happens somewhere before the function is called. Trace the execution line by line from the point of allocation, and print the vector at each step. Also check that the vector is not `delete`d.

Comment: @n.m. yup. resolved it. Had missed a return statement while creating the vector which caused this.

Answer (score 1):

OK So a number of things going wrong. Concentrating on the question, it looks like:

- `projected_tids` is not `NULL` (as you're done your check with cout)
- Your code then dumps out the address of the `projected_tids` *pointer*, (which is on the stack), not the address of the *vector*. There's nothing wrong with that, but will be a bit misleading.
- It reports that `projected_tids` contains 16 elements
- It then seg faults (i.e. invalid use of pointer) when you look at the 2nd item (`at(1)` use a 0-index). This is the big hint that something is a bit wrong.

It looks like `projected_tids` is not a valid vector. Whatever is passing the data into your A::B method is passing in a bad pointer somehow. Perhaps uninitialised? You say it's allocated, but maybe it was deleted then?

A few other bits

1. As mentioned, you're using projected_tids before checking if it was NULL
2. What's the processed_input pointer all about? There's no reference to it anywhere
3. Why not use references? They're safer and just as performant as passing pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You already call a member function on a pointer-to-object without checking for NULL first:

```
for(it_vec it = projected_tids->begin(); it != projected_tids->end(); ++it) {
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                unconditional call to member function
        if(projected_tids == NULL) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        Only here you test for NULL or not
```

So the logic in your program is flawed (big time) and anything might happen.
Also you cannot use `->at(1)` without checking that the size is at least 2. In your example the size of the vector is 0.

As an aside: why don't you pass the vectors in by reference?

Comment: please focus on the main problem rather than semantics of the code. We will look at it some other day.:)

Comment: The main problem was caused by the unclear semantics of the code. It's absolutely relevant.

Comment: It is *amazingly* relevant as witnessed by SEGFAULTing. It is *exactly* misusing of pointer semantics like this that cause SEGFAULTs to happen. The fact that `->at(1)` segfaults is exactly because there is no underlying storage, i.e. a segfault waiting to happen.

Answer (score -1):

The logic does not seem correct.

```
if(projected_tids == NULL) {                           
                cout<<"NULL";                                  
            } else {
```

you check for null.If it is null, you print null and then go ahead and dereference it.

```
 cout<<"iteration: "<<projected_tids->at(1)<<endl;
```

If it is NULL, donot dereference it.

Comment: But `NULL` is not printed in the example which segfaults. I mean it's definitely a bug, but this isn't the cause of this particular issue.

Comment: the fact that `NULL` is not printed, says something.

Comment: if you ask for trouble, you are going to get it one or another way

Comment: @basav the `if else ` statement are only for printing purposes so that scenario becomes clear. It does not create any problem and will be removed as soon as the problem is resolved.

Comment: cout<<"iteration: "<<projected_tids->at(1)<<endl;   // shouldnt that be proected_tids->at(0)??

Comment: size is 1 ie 1 element, but index has to be zero??

Comment: size of `projected_tids` is 16 as printed. Size 1 is of prefix vector